# App crashes after button click - Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

After I click the button, my app crashes

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    if (view == buttonSendMessage) {

        mDatabase.child("messages").child(myEmail).child(recipientEmail).child(String.valueOf(listViewSendMessage.getAdapter().getCount() + 1)).child("sender").setValue(myEmail);
        mDatabase.child("messages").child(myEmail).child(recipientEmail).child(String.valueOf(listViewSendMessage.getAdapter().getCount() + 1)).child("text").setValue(editTextSendMessage.getText().toString());

        //po tomto to padne na fore
    }

}
```

and here is the code in the onCreate method:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("messages/" + myEmail + "/" + recipientEmail);

    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.

            arrayList2.clear();
            arrayList.clear();

            for (final DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, Object>> m = new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, Object>>() {
                };
                final Map<String, Object> map = snapshot.getValue(m);

                sender = map.get("sender").toString();
                message = map.get("text").toString();

                arrayList2.add(map.get("sender").toString());
                arrayList2.add(map.get("text").toString());
```

.............................................etc

It crashes on the following lines:

```
sender = map.get("sender").toString();
message = map.get("text").toString();
```

But it crashes only when I click the button. The button adds data to the Firebase database. It crashes with an error that can't convert `null` to `String`, but when I open the app again everything works. It crashes only when I press button. But I don't understand why it crashes because it crashes on lines that are called in onCreate method and there it doesn't crash.

Database look:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifQiY.png)

Thanks for help.

```
{
  "messages" : {
    "samo@gmailcom" : {
      "samodubovec@gmailcom" : [ null, {
        "sender" : "samo@gmailcom",
        "text" : "hejns"
      }, {
        "sender" : "samo@gmailcom",
        "text" : "hhhhh"
      }, {
        "sender" : "samo@gmailcom",
        "text" : "dhhdhuxd"
      }, {
        "sender" : "samo@gmailcom",
        "text" : "yjjsjyy"
      } ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Looks like either map.get("sender") or map.get("text") is null and you are calling a toString on it. Please check if you are getting the value from snapshot.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Ok Frank, done :)

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use `DatabaseReference.push()` to add data instead of counting the size of the array, it's based on timestamp so it will be sorted chronologically. The error occurs because the firebase detects the data as a list instead of an object and the index 0 of that list is `null`.

When saving the data

```
String pushKey = mDatabase.child("messages").child(myEmail).child(recipientEmail).push().getKey();
mDatabase.child("messages").child(myEmail).child(recipientEmail).child(pushKey).child("sender").setValue(myEmail);
mDatabase.child("messages").child(myEmail).child(recipientEmail).child(pushKey).child("text").setValue(editTextSendMessage.getText().toString());
```

Or if you still want to use your way of indexing (incrementing from 1), you can add a checker to the snapshot entry.

```
for (final DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
        GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, Object>> m = new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, Object>>() {};
        final Map<String, Object> map = snapshot.getValue(m);

        sender = map.get("sender").toString();
        message = map.get("text").toString();

        arrayList2.add(map.get("sender").toString());
        arrayList2.add(map.get("text").toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but try both variants and nothing has changed.

Comment: can you put `Log.e("dataSnapshot", dataSnapshot.toString());` under the `onDataChange()` method and then check the output in the logcat? and are you sure that you are not violating the database rules, you can check it from the logcat after the `ValueEventListener` is attached to the database reference or post the rules in your question @Johny